# how to write 2 jquery functions in one function with different classes

Tags: jquery

How can I combine the following two JQuery functions and write it in one function. Both functions have same properties only the class names are different.

```
<script>
           $(".signupForm").validate({
            rules: {
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                confirm_password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    equalTo: "#password"
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                agree: "required"
            },
            messages: {

                password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                },
                confirm_password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                    equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
                },
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                agree: "Please accept our policy"
            }
                });

                $(".signupForm2").validate({
            rules: {
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                confirm_password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    equalTo: "#password"
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                agree: "required"
            },
            messages: {

                password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                },
                confirm_password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                    equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
                },
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                agree: "Please accept our policy"
            }
                });
    </script>
```

As you can see, both $(".signupForm").validate({}) and $(".signupForm2").validate({}) are same functions with different names.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this I suppose.

```
validateItems(".signupForm");
validateItems(".signupForm2");

function validateItems(class) {          
    $(class).validate({
        rules: {
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
        },
        confirm_password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            equalTo: "#password"
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        agree: "required"
    },
    messages: {

        password: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
        },
        confirm_password: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
            equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
        },
        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        agree: "Please accept our policy"
    }
  });
}
```